# Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just starting with RoR and i got an issue.

Earlier, I asked hear and nobody could fix it. I would like to make  a simple search form, where i would search for a product name(title).

Here is the issue: "Couldn't find Product with 'id'=search"

[Picture with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQlcY.png)

Here is my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  helper_method :get_cost

  # GET /products
  def index
    @products = Product.all
    @products = Product.search(params[:find])
  end

  # GET /products/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
     @product = Product.new
    # ingredients_ids = @product.ingredients
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :category,   :price, :quantity, {ingredient_ids: []})
    end
end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders

  enum category: ["Culinária Italiana", "Culinária Oriental", "Culinária Árabe", "Culinária Brasileira"]

  TITLE_MIN_LENGTH = 3
  DESCRIPTION_MIN_LENGTH = 2

  validates :title, presence: true, :length => {:minimum => TITLE_MIN_LENGTH}, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, presence: true, :length => {:minimum => DESCRIPTION_MIN_LENGTH}

  def self.search(search)
    if search
        where(["title LIKE ?", "%#{search}%"])
    else
        all
    end
  end


end
```

here is my view:

```
<%= form_tag(products_search_path, :method => :get) do%>
    <%= text_field_tag :find, nil, placeholder:"Insira o que está procurando"%>
    <%= submit_tag "Pesquisar", :name => nil %> 
<% end %>
```

And just to finish, here is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  get 'orders/show'
  get 'orders/new'

  resources :ingredients

  resources :products do
    get 'search'
  end

  resources :orders

  root "home#index"
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'

  get 'home/about'
  get 'home/contact'

  get "home" => "home#index"

end
```

Thanks for the attention, Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `get 'search'` in your routes.rb, but there is not `def search` in your controller. So it thinks you're trying to access the show page:

`GET products/[id]` where the `[id]` is `search` (which is clearly invalid, since all ids are numbers).

If you want to keep that `search` route, then you should set it as:
`get 'search', on: :collection`. And add `def search` to your controller with your search logic.

---

Edit:

Just adding a few tips:

- In the `def index` method, this line `@products = Product.all` is unnecessary, since you overwrite it in the following line;
- Instead of creating a different route for the `search`, it's recommended that you use the `index` with a query string. So you should:

  - remove the `get 'search'` from the `routes.rb`;
  - change your search form path to `products_path` instead of `products_search_path`;

Answer (score 0):

`search` is a collection method, so the route needs to be...

```
resources :products do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```